# Making java call to determine Apache Camel conditional routing

Tags: java, apache-camel, activemq-classic

Here is my scenario.  I have an existing processing application that currently is using camel to route ActiveMQ messages from a queue to a java application for processing, there are usually multiple instances of the app running on different nodes.

I need to be able to only route the messages to an app instance when that instance has capacity to handle it.  The app bean itself is aware of its capacity state.  The method "testCapacity" returns a boolean denoting available capacity.

I have searched as far as I can trying to find a way where I an use a call to the bean itself as the decision point for a "when" conditional.

Is this even possible, and if it is possible how can this be achieved.

```
<route>
    <from uri="activemq:queue:myQueue" />
    <when>
        <xpath>idontknowwhattoputhere("bean:javaBean?method=testCapacity")</xpath>
        <to uri="bean:javaBean?method=doThings" />
    </when>
</route>
```

Comment: Dig into Bean Language http://camel.apache.org/bean-language.html

Answer (score 3):

```
<route>
    <from uri="activemq:queue:myQueue" />
    <when>
        <simple>${bean:javaBean?method=testCapacity}</simple>
        <to uri="bean:javaBean?method=doThings" />
    </when>
</route>
```